# Access database from another server from azure webapp

Tags: mysql, azure

Suppose I have mysql database in serverA(not azure) and I have webapp in azure. How can I access database that is in serverA from my azure webapp?

Answer (score 0):

AS long as you give relevant firewall and access permissions, you can in theory connect to your database from any other server.

(as long as you are able to make it accessible online, via a public IP)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a VNET in Azure and then connect this VNET to your on premise VPN assuming serverA is an on premise server.

[Connect an on-premises network to a Microsoft Azure virtual network](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn786406.aspx)

Further you will have to pull your web app under your VNET.

[enter link description here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/)

But in case, serverA is available on internet then yes you should be able to connect after modifying your firewall rules. Please note if you have IP based restrictions at MySQL side, you might have to white list all azure website IP range depending on your region.